# Voice Control is launching on its own,also since updating to ios10 there is no menu to turn off Siri between Sounds and Touch id and password

Tags: siri, voice

Since updating to ios10, voice control intermittently launches itself,also between Sounds and Touch id/password under settings the menu for Siri has disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Siri is disabled under Restrictions. To re-enable Siri, go into Settings > General > Restrictions, enter your Restrictions password, and enable **Siri and Dictation**.

[image: Restrictions menu]